# How to use a hook instead of context provider using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to access isLoading state ineach component of the main component. basically when load() in useAnother hook starts and ends i set loading state to true and false.

below is my code without context provider,

```
function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }
    }
}

function Main ({user}: Props) {
    useAnother(user.id); //fetching isLoading here from useHook
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <React.suspense>
                <Switch>
                    <Route 
                        path="/" 
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <FirstComp {...routeProps} />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route 
                        path="/items" 
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <SecondComp {...routeProps} />
                        )}
                    />
                   //many other routes like these
                </Switch>
            </React.suspense>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

Now with using context provider

```
interface LoadingContextState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    setIsLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialLoadingState: LoadingContextState = {
    isLoading: false, setIsLoading: () => {},
};

export const LoadingContext = React.createContext<LoadingContextState>(
    initialLoadingState
);

export const LoadingContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
         <LoadingContext.Provider
             value={{
                 isLoading,
                 setIsLoading,
             }}
         >
             {children}
         </LoadingContext.Provider>
     );
 };

 function App() {
     return (
         <LoadingContextProvider>
             <Main/>
         </LoadingContextProvider>
     );
 }

 function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const {setIsLoading} = React.useContext(LoadingContext);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }
    }
}

function Main ({user}: Props) {
    useAnother(user.id);
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <React.suspense>
                <Switch>
                    <Route 
                        path="/" 
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <FirstComp {...routeProps} />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route 
                        path="/items" 
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <SecondComp {...routeProps} />
                        )}
                    />
                   //many other routes like these
                </Switch>
            </React.suspense>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

function FirstComponent () {
    const {isLoading} = React.useContext(LoadingContext);
    return (
        <Wrapper isLoading={isLoading}/>
    );
}
```

this works. but i dont want to use context provider instead is it possible to use hook instead of context for this.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

}

Now with using context provider

```
interface LoadingContextState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    setIsLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialLoadingState: LoadingContextState = {
    isLoading: false, setIsLoading: () => {},
};

export const LoadingContext = React.createContext<LoadingContextState>(
    initialLoadingState
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you choose to return the value of `isLoading` from `useAnother` hook.

```js
function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }
    }

    return isLoading; // return the isLoading value from the hook
}
```

When you call `useAnother` hook in the `Main` component you can get the `isLoading` value and pass it as props to the children of `Main` component. 
For example,

```js
const isLoading = useAnother(user.id)

// when you render FirstComp pass isLoading as prop also, the FirstComp
// needs to have appropriate code for handling the `isLoading` value
 <FirstComp {...routeProps} isLoading={isLoading} />
```

***The issue with this approach***, suppose you have another component which is a child of the `FirstComponent` and it also needs the `isLoading` value. To provide the `isLoading` value you have to pass `isLoading` drilling the prop through several components in the hierarchy which is an anti-pattern.

That is why I suggest keep using the context API approach,

*Using contexts can generate some complex boilerplate code when using typescript, but it saves you from drilling the prop in the component hierarchy.*

Comment: hmm thanks..but is not it possible to return state and setstate in some new use hook and use it in the useAnother hook to set state and access the isLoading state from new use hook in first or second components?

Comment: In that case, the new hook will create a new set of local state variables in the first and second components. There will be no shared state.

Comment: hmm so it is not possible to use a new hook for my example.

Comment: In theory, it is possible but it requires even more complex boilerplate code to work than a simple context.